# Refreshing Google Map Android (API 2)

Tags: android, google-maps, refresh

Is it possible to auto refresh google maps after every couple of minutes to view any changes that have been made. (Also, refresh if a action is done, such as if a button is pressed.)

For example, in my app I am displaying a text when a user comes near a river, however because the map does not refresh the message is not shown to the user unless there come near a river and close and reopen the app.

e.g. when user comes near one of the lat and long, it will say "You are near a River recorded in our database, this river is marked as 1".

Answer (score 0):

If this is for getting user location, then you should access [Location Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location) using the [Location API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). You can check for whenever you location changes by using a [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).

Comment: I am already getting user location but the problem is when a user gets near a certain location (lat and long) I want a message to pop up. However because the map doesn't auto update, the user is required to do some action in order to see the message, for example, they need to close and reopen the app.